# sunlight and sensors for garage doors

Tags: doors, garage

I have found that the light reflecting off the garage floor also causes a problem.  High noon, both sensors in the shadow and still a problem.  Put some landscaping black and fixed it.  Next morning, only transmitter in the sun, black all along the floor didn't fix it?  going to try cleaning and sunglasses.  The installation has been there for 15 years with no problem!

Comment: Might be time to replace the sensors.  They do loose their ability to "sense"

Comment: Your forgot to ask a question in your 'question'.